# How to find "#VALUE" cells in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007, find, find-and-replace

In Excel 2007 I have two sheets:

- sheets1 with data
- sheets2 links with some formulas data from sheets1

If a formula does not work in sheets2 I have cell that shows `#VALUE!`, but in the bar I can see the formula. I would like to check if in the sheets2 there are any cell with #VALUE to be corrected.

It is not possible to use FIND function to search for "#VALUE", because in the bar there are no those chars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set up the following option:

*Look in:* `Values`

[image]

If you want to count `#VALUE!` errors in Excel 2007, you may use the following array formula (entered using **Ctrl+Shift+Enter** instead of regular Enter):

```
=SUM(IFERROR(--(ERROR.TYPE(sheets1!$B$1:$B$10)=3),0))
```

[image]

<sup>Note that array formulas always do calculations for every cell in the reference, so providing the whole column will not be efficient.</sup>